# Adding bindings for ed2k:// links with xdg-open?

Tags: files, file-sharing, freedesktop

I want to use a customized program to handle "ed2k://" links ,  it already got a "*.desktop" file , but how can I bind it with xdg-open as the default handler ?

Since I don't know the exact mimetype of "ed2k://" links , I had to ask here

**Temporary solution**

Modify xdg-open to handle "ed2k:%2F%2F" links , [source code](https://github.com/CaledoniaProject/Gentoo-Scripts/blob/master/xdg-open)

Still looking for standard work arounds

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mimetype in question is:

```
x-scheme-handler/ed2k
```

I just tried it.

I installed amule and created a file *userapp-amule.desktop* in *~/.local/share/applications*:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=aMule
Name[en_US]=userapp-amule
Exec=amule %u
Icon=amule
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;P2P;
Comment=A client for the eD2k network
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/ed2k
```

and I also added this line:

```
x-scheme-handler/ed2k=userapp-amule.desktop
```

to *~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list* under [Default Applications] and [Added Associations]. I then opened an ed2k link with xdg-open (note the quotes):

```
xdg-open 'ed2k://|file|Some.String.Here%5D.%E4%B8%93%E8%BE%91.%28PDF%29.rar|74945828|3788c937a5d436cff6e6808b02d07339|h=4jk63hyesnpxk6xwm5rwgmb2mljxtixz|/'
```

and it worked:

```
: Initialising aMule SVN compiled with wxGTK2 v2.8.12 (Snapshot: rev. 10792)
: Checking if there is an instance already running...
: No other instances are running.
: ListenSocket: Ok.
: Loading temp files from /home/me/.aMule/Temp.
```

Comment: That is great !

Comment: New versions of Ubuntu have config at `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Comment: Also `MimeType=x-scheme-handler` in .desktop and `x-scheme-handler` in [Default Applications] was not needed

Comment: @AndreyP - indeed, this is a very old post... [as I see, defaults have changed](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_MIME_Applications#mimeapps.list)... feel free to edit or update the answer if you have the time,  I made it _community wiki_ so anyone with at least 100 rep can edit it.